# Model property values are null on POST when action parameter is called "model"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Did they change something in AspNetCore that no longer allows you to use the parameter name "model" on POST actions?

If I do this, the DeviceModel property values are populated on postback:

```
[HttpPost] 
public IActionResult Create(DeviceModel device)
```

However if I change the parameter name from "device" to "model" the property values are null.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(DeviceModel model)
```

Is this a bug in AspNetCore or did they change something?

I can't find anything saying that the parameter can't be called "model" and in previous MVC versions this worked fine.

Comment: Did you try other names?

Comment: this generally happens when you have  a property called `Model` inside your `DeviceModel`.

Comment: @Mate yeah, seems only "model" has the issue.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane interesting, my DeviceModel DOES have a Model property. Just removed the property and tried it... works! So is that a bug? seems strange that a property in my Model broke it.

Comment: it's not a bug. it actually makes sense. in case you intended to serialize a string. it's odd, i faced the exact issue just a couple of days back

Comment: I really threw me off, I had an older MVC project that I am porting to core and they all have the action parameter named "model" and a few simply started failing and I couldn't figure out why it was when the logic and code worked fine in the previous version. Thanks for the information and insight. :)

Comment: yep. I have used mvc.net for five years and only noticed this recently. I guessed it was a new design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you can also have actions as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string model)
```

This would take a key posted as "model" and get its string value. From your comments, you have a property called `Model` in your class. This means your posted data includes a key called "model".
The framework first tries to deserialize the value of your posted `Model` and assign its value to `DeviceModel model` since the names matches. Once the deserialization fails, you have a `model` object with default values.

Comment: Discovered this is by design, https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3735

Comment: yeah... this logic is actually useful when you need to pass a list as an array etc. js can serialize and post.